# idle "untitled" but won't let me save as anything

Tags: python, save

This is all I have as "untitled" but when I try to run, the window pops up "source must be saved" so I click ok and name it in the C drive that comes up automatically which is C:Users....appData\local\Programs\Python\Python 38-32
but the name does not change and if I try to run again the same thing happens again and again.
I'm new....can anyone help please?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import csv
datasource=r (‘C:\DATA ANALYSIS OPTIMIZATION\TrumpForbesRichestAmericans.csv’)
data=np.genfromtxt(datasource,cols=range(0,4),delimiter=’,’,names=True,missing_values='',filling_values=’nan’)
y=np
print(y)
```

Comment: Your quotes seems odd... Normal Python quotes are `'`.

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And please learn how to *[edit]* your questions to improve them.